# Angularfire2 query using navParams not working

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, ionic3, angularfire2

I want to get some data using `navParams` but it is not working but if I provide static value then it's work. I don't know what is wrong. Here is my code that does not work and return empty

```
console.log(this.navParams.get('id')) // prints 10
const id = this.navParams.get('id');
this.categoryRef = this.db.list('/category', ref => ref.orderByChild('id').equalTo(id));
this.category = this.categoryRef.snapshotChanges().map(changes => {
    return changes.map(c => ({ key: c.payload.key, ...c.payload.val() }));
});
```

if I give static value then it works like

```
const id = 10;
this.categoryRef = this.db.list('/category', ref => ref.orderByChild('id').equalTo(id));
this.category = this.categoryRef.snapshotChanges().map(changes => {
    return changes.map(c => ({ key: c.payload.key, ...c.payload.val() }));
});
```

Comment: Where you call this method? Lifecyle event?

Comment: I have tried it in both `ionViewDidLoad()` and `constructor`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually I found an issue on firebase database side. My id was not stored with double quotes like `"1"` it was saved as `1` then I make it to double quotes and it works fine then
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Can you try like below?

```
myId:number;//declare a global variable

constructor(){
   this.myId=this.navParams.get('id');
   this.categoryRef = this.db.list('/category', ref => 
           ref.orderByChild('id').equalTo(this.myId));
   this.category = this.categoryRef.snapshotChanges().map(changes => {
           return changes.map(c => ({ key: c.payload.key, ...c.payload.val() }));
});
}
```

Comment: You can debug no? What is the value of `this.myId`?

Comment: `console.log(this.myId);` prints 10

Comment: Then what is the problem there?

Comment: that is strange. If I use param then result is empty.

Comment: Here no version issue. You told `this.myId' has `10` when coming from `params` then that is what you need no?

Comment: actually I move form one page to other page using a param and that param I use to fetch data from database. In my case that param is getting but databse query not working with param

Comment: Sampath any other way ti fix this issue. I am stuck here.